# Cuando quiero probar mi login en postman me sale error 401

Tags: mysql, angular, login, jwt

Este es el codigo de mi auth controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class AuthController {
    @Autowired][1]][1]
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    @Autowired
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    @Autowired
    UsuarioService usuarioService;
    @Autowired
    RolService rolService;
    @Autowired
    JwtProvider jwtProvider;
    
    @PostMapping("/nuevo")
    public ResponseEntity<?> nuevo(@Valid @RequestBody NuevoUsuario nuevoUsuario, BindingResult bindingResult){
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors())
            return new ResponseEntity(new Mensaje("Campos mal puestos o email invalido"),HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        
        if(usuarioService.existsByNombreUsuario(nuevoUsuario.getNombreUsuario()))
            return new ResponseEntity(new Mensaje("Ese nombre de usuario ya existe"), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        
        if(usuarioService.existsByEmail(nuevoUsuario.getEmail()))
            return new ResponseEntity(new Mensaje("Ese email ya existe"), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        
        Usuario usuario = new Usuario(nuevoUsuario.getNombre(), nuevoUsuario.getNombreUsuario(),
            nuevoUsuario.getEmail(), passwordEncoder.encode(nuevoUsuario.getPassword()));
        
        Set<Rol> roles = new HashSet<>();
        roles.add(rolService.getByRolNombre(RolNombre.ROLE_USER).get());
        
        if(nuevoUsuario.getRoles().contains("admin"))
            roles.add(rolService.getByRolNombre(RolNombre.ROLE_ADMIN).get());
        usuario.setRoles(roles);
        usuarioService.save(usuario);
        
        return new ResponseEntity(new Mensaje("Usuario guardado"),HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<JwtDto> login(@Valid @RequestBody LoginUsuario loginUsuario, BindingResult bindingResult){
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors())
            return new ResponseEntity(new Mensaje("Campos mal puestos"), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        
        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
        loginUsuario.getNombreUsuario(), loginUsuario.getPassword()));
        
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        
        String jwt = jwtProvider.generateToken(authentication);
        
        UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
        
        JwtDto jwtDto = new JwtDto(jwt, userDetails.getUsername(), userDetails.getAuthorities());
        
        return new ResponseEntity(jwtDto, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    
    
}
```

El usuario ya fué generado en MySQL. Lo generé directamente desde una tabla de ahi porque en postman no me dejaba en auth/nuevo. Lo hice y todo ok, se guardó el usuario correctamente, pero cuando quiero probar el login con ese usuario me sale ese error.
No se si hice mal en crear el usuario desde MySQL o si hay un problema con el jwt. Pero si alguien pudiera darme una mano sería genial.
La aplicacion ya tiene el deploy hecho y cuando lo pruebo desde el entorno local me da este error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080